# Puppeteer Error: No Element found for selector (Manually verified selector works in dev tools)

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to fill a password field using puppeteer, but I can't select the node

```
.... 
    await page.focus('[data-testid="IdentifierFirstIdentifierInput"]') 
    await page.keyboard.type('test@gmail.com')
    let signinBtn = await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="IdentifierFirstSubmitButton"]');
    await signinBtn.click()

    
    //Both of these selectors work in chrome dev tools
    //await page.focus('[data-testid="currentPasswordInput"]')
    //await page.focus('[aria-label="Password"]')
....
```

both result in Error: No element found for selector...

Comment: Something working in devtools offers very little guarantee that it'll work in Puppeteer. DevTools lets you query shadow DOM roots and iframes, runs after selectors have loaded, isn't susceptible to bot detection and blocking, etc. Without the site or a runnable [mcve], this question isn't really actionable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some JS that runs after `signinBtn.click()`

It seems that `page.focus()` is firing too early, before the DOM is modified.

[`page.waitForSelector()`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforselector) works fine.